# Subdomains with different themes on a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a three WordPress themes that I need to present to management for a final selection of the theme to implement for production. I need to present them as `dev1.domain.tld`, `dev2.domain.tld`, and `dev3.domain.tld`.

The subdomains are all the same installation of WordPress, however I simply want the subdomains to control which theme is loaded for the visitor.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Comment: FYI, I am aware that MultiSite could be used, however this is a temporary setup for simply facilitating a quick evaluation of themes and MultiSite has caused some problems with a couple of plugins we have in place.  Ideally there would be a way to do this with a regular 'ole WP install.

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930837/wordpress-using-different-theme-subdomain-or-multisite/70530407#70530407

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply creating three separate installs in each sub-domain folder then connecting to the same DB?

Not 100% if that would work but i don't see why not.